# Chrome Extension error trying to send array from content script to popup script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

I am attempting to find all of the images on the webpage the user is currently on, and display them when the user clicks on the extension. I have looked at a lot of posts and seemingly found the best way to do this: have the popup.js script message the content.js script when it is activated, and then have the content.js script get the images and send it back to the popup.js script. However, I always get an error (shown below). These are the relevant files:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Picture Finder",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": false
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]

}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Picture Finder</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <h1><center>Picture Finder</center></h1>
  <img id="pic" src="" height="400" width="400">
 </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getContent"}, 

    function(response) {
        console.log(response); //this never gets logged
        document.getElementById('pic').src = response[0].src;
    });
});
```

content.js

```
var picArray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var srcArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < picArray.length; i++){
    srcArray.push(picArray[i].src);
}
//console.log(picArray); //this gets logged correctly
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(message.type){
        case "getContent":
            console.log(srcArray);//this never gets logged
            sendResponse(srcArray);
            break;
        default:
            console.error("unexpected message: ", message);
    }
});
```

I noticed that I get the following error when clicking on my extension and inspecting it:

> Error in response to tabs.query: Error: Invalid value for argument 3. Property 'type': Unexpected property.
>       at Object.callback (chrome-extension://mhnnhbbcahnfjmfgofalcmikdedelicg/popup.js:2:17)
>       at chrome-extension://mhnnhbbcahnfjmfgofalcmikdedelicg/popup.js:1:13

I am very new to developing chrome extensions and don't really have any idea how to fix this. The error seems to suggest that the callback function is an invalid argument in chrome.tabs.query but I am not sure how. Thanks for help.
Note that my background.js script is an empty file.

Comment: In this `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getContent"}, ` why you are passing tab id? If it is needed you should pass it as `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({id: tabs[0].id, type: "getContent"}, function() {}) `.

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed it is posted above! I just have one function in it

Comment: @Apb False, the invocation is correct.

Comment: @Apb ok thank you I changed it to the way you suggested and I now get a new error: >TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work anyway, because you can't pass a DOM node through Messaging (it's not JSON-serializable).

You should be passing only the properties you care about, e.g. if you need `src`'s - extract an array of them and pass that array.

**Update:** Ah, I see the reason for the error now. You're using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` while in this case you should be using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` - it chokes on an invalid invocation (the first argument, if present, should be a string - you try to pass a number, so it's interpreted as the message, and then the object confuses it).

To fix, just replace `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` with `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`.

Comment: thank you for helping. I updated my content.js script to get an array of src url strings from the picArray, and then send that back to the popup.js. However I still get the same error that I originally posted. My popup.js script is the same as my original post, and I don't have the comma error you pointed out. Any ideas of what might cause this error? Is it possible the array is still not valid? (I updated the content.js above)

Comment: I found the error - because your code is quite correct it was hard to spot. Also, some advice - gather the array in the content script when you receive a message, not when the content script runs, you'll get a more up to date state.